# Create JavaScript function that runs while user can still interact with page

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm creating a web application that has a function that takes several seconds to complete. I want the user to still be able to interact with the page while that function is running. I thought the best way to do this is with [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and/or [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but I have tried what felt like every combination, and it will still not work.

I have simplified what I have, and it can be found in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheOmnimax/c5toxz48/2). Here is the JavaScript file:

```
const statusContainer = document.querySelector('#status')
const button = document.querySelector('#button')

button.onclick = function () {
  button.innerHTML = 'Clicked!'
}

myFunc()

function myFunc() {
  console.log('Working...')
  statusContainer.innerHTML = 'Working...'
  longTest()
  statusContainer.innerHTML = 'Done'
  console.log('Done')
}

function longTest() {
  new Promise(function () {
    console.log('Starting')
    var counter = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < 4000000000; i++) {
      counter++
    }
    console.log('Completed long test')
  })
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<script src="async_test.js" defer></script>
<div id="status">Not started</div>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Currently, when you click the button, it does not react until the `longTest()` function is done running. How can I set it up so the user can still click buttons and interact with the page while that function is running? According to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts#asynchronous_code), web workers could work, but there may be a better way. Thanks in advance!

(If you're curious, this is for a [Boggle game](http://maxshaberman.com/games/boggle/) I am developing. When the board is created, it finds every playable word, but it freezes for a few seconds before the board is actually displayed, since it takes a few seconds to run.)

Comment: Try using webworkers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

Comment: JS is singlethreaded, and once a function has started to execute it's not interrupted (unless there is some async operation like a webrequest). Your loop cannot be interrupted, so once it started executing it occupies the only available thread until it's finished.